# Java mysqlIO Ошибка

Tags: java

```
GQueryPasswd:account is Ð½Ñ Ð¼Ð° , login ip is 1599274334 
Sending query to acquire password 
Prepare procedure call:{call acquireuserpasswd(?,?,?)} 
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x8E\xC3\xB0\xC2\xBC...' for column 'name1' at row 1 
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:882) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.execute(CallableStatement.java:759) 
at application.procedure.handler.execute(handler.java:197) 
at com.goldhuman.account.storage.acquireIdPasswd(storage.java:419) 
at protocol.MatrixPasswd.Server(Unknown Source) 
at com.goldhuman.IO.Protocol.Rpc.Process(Unknown Source) 
at com.goldhuman.IO.Protocol.Task.run(Unknown Source) 
at com.goldhuman.Common.ThreadPool.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) 
acquireIdPasswd exception:account=Ð½Ñ Ð¼Ð°
```

Вот функция в которой возникла ошибка, к сожалению запроса при которой возникает ошибки нет, но как я полагаю в name1 попадают вот это "Ð½Ñ Ð¼Ð°"

```
<procedure name="acquireuserpasswd" connection="auth0" operate="replaceA"> 
 <parameter name="name1"     sql-type="varchar(64)"  java-type="java.lang.String"  in="true"  out="false" /> 
 <parameter name="uid1"      sql-type="integer"      java-type="java.lang.Integer" in="false" out="true" /> 
 <parameter name="passwd1"   sql-type="varchar(64)"  java-type="java.lang.String"  in="false" out="true" /> 
</procedure>
```

Comment: Пытаетесь вставить некорректную строку в поле name1. Напишите тип/размерность поля name1 и приведите пример, что хотите вставить

Comment: Подправил вопрос